# Use javascript variable within ASP.NET code blocks

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a rather simple problem which I can't seem to work out.

I have a javascript code block;

```
<script>
 var user = {
       id: 1,
       username: 'myname' 
};

window.location.href = '<%# Page.GetRouteUrl("member", New With {.member = --username--})%>';
</script>
```

In the above code, I need to replace --username-- with user.username from my javascript object.. I would be grateful if you could help me accomplish this.

**EDIT**

I cannot get username from server side as username is the name of the user from facebook which I use the javascript API to get...

Comment: Why dont you get the `username` from server side and use in `GetRouteUrl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use some placeholder for username on server side, and replace it with real username on client side:

```
<script>
 var user = {
       id: 1,
       username: 'myname' 
};

window.location.href = '<%# Page.GetRouteUrl("member", New With {.member = "__USERNAME__"})%>'.replace('__USERNAME__', user.username);
</script>
```

Comment: very interesting solution that I have not thought of before.. Will try this and let you know.. Are you sure this is like the most optimal and correct way to do though? I mean is this how it is correctly made normally?

Comment: I accepted this answer because it simply 'works'. I am not too confortable with this solution however, it sounds better than having a server side literal.

Comment: real solution (without a literal) is to create a server-side action (for mvc) or some other handler (non-mvc); than post userId to that action from js, and redirect to correct url from server code. I can add a full sample for MVC, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
window.location.href = '<%# Page.GetRouteUrl("member", New With {.member = %>' + user.username + '<%})%>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't

**explanation:**
at time 0: The asp.net code block will be evaluated at the server side

at time 1: The evaluated markup will be sent to the client (transforming all the server side code block to HTML)

at time 1.1: The JavaScript will be evaluated on the browser, so here you **can't access the past**

**the golden rule is:**

- Server Side code can generate Client Side Code (e.g. Literal Control can generate HTML and JavaSCript)
- Client Side code **cannot generate Server Side Code** (JavaScript or HTML concatenation cannot generate Literal Control)

e.g. passing data from server side to client side

```
<div><asp:Literal runat="server" text="ServerSideVariableOnly" /></div>
```

OR

```
<script>
 var pageurl = '<asp:Literal runat="server" text="AnotherServerSideVariable" />'
</script>
```

to do what you want you have two options:

1. you have to make an ajax call (client <--- server) to get further information or,
2. populate the required data before loading the page.

Comment: Well, you might be right. Just because you are right, I had to accept a 'hacky' solution. I cannot form my string in server side since it gets set in client side however I am sure this would also be a great answer for those who might run into a different situation than I currently have.. Thanks for the answer man..